# "cannot assign because part of method group"

Tags: c#, class, methods, method-group

I have a form with the following code :

```
public partial class frmSalesTax : Form
{
    public frmSalesTax()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //declare variables
    decimal ItemPrice = 00.00m;
    decimal TaxAmount = 00.08m;
    decimal TotalAmount = 00.00m;

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (decimal.TryParse(txtItemPrice.Text, out ItemPrice))
            {
                //Instantiated instance of a class here. 
                CTransaction Calc;
                Calc = new CTransaction();

                //set properties to calc tax amount.
                Calc.SalesTaxRate = .08m;
                Calc.TxtItemPrice = ItemPrice;

                //call the method in the instance of the class
                TaxAmount = Calc.CalculateTax();

                //Set tax amount property to be available for the calc.
                Calc.CalculateTax = TaxAmount;

                //call the method in the instance of the class.
                TotalAmount = Calc.CalculateTotal();

                //Display the values
                lblTaxAmt.Text = TaxAmount.ToString("c");
                lblTotal.Text = TotalAmount.ToString("c");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter a numeric value please");
                txtItemPrice.Focus();
                txtItemPrice.SelectAll();

                lblTaxAmt.Text = string.Empty;
                lblEndTotal.Text = string.Empty;

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Critical Error");
        }
    }
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

---

and a class :

```
public class CTransaction
{
    //Create private fields
    private decimal salesTaxRate = .07m;
    private decimal ItemPrice;
    private decimal taxAmount;

    //Define the properties
    public decimal SalesTaxRate
    {
        get { return salesTaxRate;}
        set { salesTaxRate = value;}
}
    public decimal TxtItemPrice
    {
        get { return ItemPrice; }
        set { ItemPrice = value;}
    }

    //Custom methods
    public decimal CalculateTax()
    {
        return ItemPrice * SalesTaxRate;
    }

    public decimal CalculateTotal()
    {
        return ItemPrice + taxAmount;
    }
}
```

---

Im getting the "cannot assign to 'CalculateTax' because it  is a method group.  (Form1.cs .. line 54 .. column 21)

The form has the following fields on it for the user to interact with
txtItemPrice    (textbox)
3 - buttons (calc, clear, exit) 
lblTaxAmount (which should display how my tax is being applied to the item. 
lblEndTOtal (which should be the itemPrice + TaxAmount

Comment: `CalculateTax` is a method. You can't assign a method a value.  I'm not sure what your intention really is.

Comment: Yep, @Jonesopolis is right, just remove `Calc.CalculateTax = TaxAmount;`

Comment: I agree - in the `btnCalc_Click` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem line:

```
                //Set tax amount property to be available for the calc.
                Calc.CalculateTax = TaxAmount;
```

You are trying to assign a value (TaxAmount) to a method (CalculateTax). You can't do that. If you are trying to set the tax rate then you need to add a public property to allow it to be set:

```
Calc.TaxAmount = TaxAmount;
```

Then in your Calc class:

```
public decimal TaxAmount
{
    get { return taxAmount; }
    set { taxAmount = value; }
}
```

Then everything should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your line Calc.CalculateTax is a method in order for you to pass a value through a method, you should pass it as a parameter.

In your code, i would make a change on the CTransaction Class:

```
public decimal CalculateTotal(decimal taxAmount)
{
     return itemPrice + taxAmount;
}
```

And in your `frmSalesTax`, you just have to remove your line:

```
//Set tax amount property to be available for the calc.
                Calc.CalculateTax = TaxAmount;
```

And then in your line , `TotalAmount = Calc.CalculateTotal();`, the `taxAmount` variable as a parameter for `TotalAmount` method. And it should be like that:

```
TotalAmount = Calc.CalculateTotal(taxAmount);
```

It just should work like you expect.

For more information check these links:

[C# Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx)

[C# Passing Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)